# Find total number of spokes in the wheel from image - OpenCV (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning

I have a couple of images with a carriage wheel. 
They are grayscale – pixel levels vary from minimal value (**black**) to the maximal value (**white**).
The wheel is rendered as a single connected component.
Wheel parts are colored white, and background is black.

Example image 1:

[image: Example image 1]

Example image 2:

[image: Example image 2]

This is wheel with it's parts:

[image: This is wheel with it's parts]

I've already found center of the wheel axle, but I also want to find **number of all spokes** in the picture and **number of broken spokes**.

Here's some **facts** about the image: 
1. Every spoke is aligned with the hoop radius 
2. Minimal angular width of each spoke is **2 degrees** 
3. Angular separation between any two of the spokes centerlines is at least **10 degrees** 
4. Spokes are not placed at equidistant angles 
5. If the spoke is not fully connecting the hoop and the axle, the gap in the spoke is at least **10 pixels** 
6. An axle - represented by a filled circle with a minimal radius of **10 pixels** 
7. A hoop – represented by two circles concentric with the wheel axle. Its minimal thickness is **10 pixels**

So, here is my code for detecting an axle of the wheel. I used **HoughCircles** to detected smallest circle.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


img_bgr = cv2.imread('wheel.png')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img_gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 300, 
np.array([]), 10, 30, 10, 50)
center_x = 0
center_y = 0

if circles is not None:
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

    for i in circles[0, :]:
        cv2.circle(img_bgr, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.circle(img_bgr, (i[0], i[1]), 2, (0, 0, 255), 3)
        center_x = i[0]
        center_y = i[1]

print("%d %d" % (center_x, center_y))
plt.imshow(img_bgr, cmap='gray', interpolation='bicubic')
plt.show()
```

And this is the result. 
[image: Found center of the wheel] 
Also, I want to **find the length of the longest arc** not intercepted by any spoke φmax (in degrees). Consider the wheel to be flat, i.e. all parts of the wheel lay in one plane.

I tried to find edges with **Canny** and **HoughLinesP**, but I got stuck and don't know what to do next.

```
threshhold, threshhold_img = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
edges = cv2.Canny(threshhold_img, 150, 200, 3, 5)
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi / 180, 30, 20, 5)

for line in lines:
    for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
        print("(%d, %d) && (%d, %d)" % (x1, y1, x2, y2))
        cv2.line(img_bgr, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 0), 3)
```

This is the image of marked spokes: 
[image: This is the image of marked spokes]

I'm new with OpenCV so any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: don't explain how the image looks like. provide the actual image.

Comment: @Piglet I added two examples above. Here is first without found center: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPjiL.png.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the spokes, sample the image with a small circle, close to the axle and a large one, close to the hoop. These will intercept white (angular) intervals. Join the middles of the intervals and check continuity of the spokes. When an interval is missing, you can extrapolate to the center.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this looks very nice! But I struggle with finding medium circle. I set different boundaries, but it isn't work every time. 
medium_circle = cv2.HoughCircles(img_gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 200, np.array([]), 10, 30, 60, 110). And I don't know how did you find spokes and marked it with these brown lines. Should I crop the image to the size of medium circle?

Comment: @dzimiks: what do you call the *medium* circle ?

Comment: Circle after the smallest, because the hoop is also a circle. Bigger circle at your picture actually.

Comment: what did you use to find spokes? You literally found all this in 5 minutes, but I've been trying to do it for 2 days. How can I check continuity of the spokes and more important, how to find it? I used Canny, HoughCircles, but I didn't get picture as you.

Comment: @dzimiks: come on, this was obviously drawn by hand. Sampling along a circle is not a big deal, nor finding constant intervals along a profile.

Comment: Haha I hope I'll find the way. I appreciate your help. :)